# How to use MongoDump in MongoShell?

Tags: mongodb

I upgraded my free cluster to M10 cluster and I don't want to pay anymore and want to downgrade to free tier cluster again
However they wont allow me to downgrade.
So I need to create a new free cluster and dump my databases(collections) to the new cluster

However when I open MongoDB compass and in the MongoSH run mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://

It says Unexpected token, expected ";"

are there any other solutions to this?
thank you

Comment: `mongodump` is a operating system command line tool.

Comment: i have to do this from command terminal/